# Macbook freezes, disk errors, symptoms of SSD death?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, hardware, ssd

Macbook freezes, system disk "disappears" from system, I get errors about reading/writing. Spinning ball of death appears on the screen, I am able to move pointer for a few seconds after first symptoms but then computer freezes completely.

After hard reset everything is ok. After 30-60 minutes of work it happens again.

Since I am able to use Macbook after reset it doesn't look like problems with SSD, does it?

Tried to boot from Live CD — system freezes too.

Memtest — perfect results for short test, system freezes on 40+ minutes test.

Tried to make fresh installation of Mavericks — system freezes after some time spent for install.

ps. Macbook 13" 2011, 10.8, SSD Crucial M4 (about two years old).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the problem never appeared after I replaced SSD, so probably the answer is yes.